# Conditionally create an "Other" category in categorical column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have a `DataFrame` `df` with one column, `category` created with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rand
from string import ascii_uppercase

rand.seed(1010)

df = pd.DataFrame()
values = list()
for i in range(0,1000):   
    category = (''.join(rand.choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(1)))
    values.append(category)

df['category'] = values
```

The frequency counts for each value are:

```
df['category'].value_counts()
Out[95]: 
P    54
B    50
T    48
V    46
I    46
R    45
F    43
K    43
U    41
C    40
W    39
E    39
J    39
X    37
M    37
Q    35
Y    35
Z    34
O    33
D    33
H    32
G    32
L    31
N    31
S    29
```

I would like to make a new value in `df['category']` column called "other" and assign all values of `df['category']` that have a `value_count` less than `35`.

Can someone help me out with this?

Let me know if you need anything more from me

**EDIT from @EdChum proposed solution**

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rand
from string import ascii_uppercase

rand.seed(1010)

df = pd.DataFrame()
values = list()
for i in range(0,1000):   
    category = (''.join(rand.choice(ascii_uppercase) for i in range(1)))
    values.append(category)

df['category'] = values
df['category'].value_counts()

df.loc[df['category'].isin((df['category'].value_counts([df['category'].value_‌​counts() < 35]).index), 'category'] = 'other'

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    df.loc[df['category'].isin((df['category'].value_counts()[df['category'].value_‌​counts() < 35]).index), 'category'] = 'other'
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note that I am using Python 2.7 on the Spyder IDE (I tried the proposed solution in iPython and Python console windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` to generate a boolean mask to mask the values and then set these to 'other' using `loc`:

```
In [71]:
df.loc[df['category'].isin((df['category'].value_counts()[df['category'].value_counts() < 35]).index), 'category'] = 'other'
df

Out[71]:
    category
0      other
1      other
2          A
3          V
4          U
5          D
6          T
7          G
8          S
9          H
10     other
11     other
12     other
13     other
14         S
15         D
16         B
17         P
18         B
19     other
20     other
21         F
22         H
23         G
24         P
25     other
26         M
27         V
28         T
29         A
..       ...
970        E
971        D
972    other
973        P
974        V
975        S
976        E
977    other
978        H
979        V
980        O
981    other
982        O
983        Z
984    other
985        P
986        P
987    other
988        O
989    other
990        P
991        X
992        E
993        V
994        B
995        P
996        B
997        P
998        Q
999        X

[1000 rows x 1 columns]
```

Breaking the above down:

```
In [74]:
df['category'].value_counts() < 35

Out[74]:
W    False
B    False
C    False
V    False
H    False
P    False
T    False
R    False
U    False
K    False
E    False
Y    False
M    False
F    False
O    False
A    False
D    False
Q    False
N     True
J     True
S     True
G     True
Z     True
I     True
X     True
L     True
Name: category, dtype: bool

In [76]:    
df['category'].value_counts()[df['category'].value_counts() < 35]

Out[76]:
N    34
J    33
S    33
G    33
Z    32
I    31
X    31
L    30
Name: category, dtype: int64
```

we can then use `isin` against the `.index` values and set the rows to 'other'

Answer (score 5):

There's an example in a [Unit 2 assignment notebook](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/DS-Unit-2-Linear-Models/blob/master/module3-ridge-regression/LS_DS_213_assignment.ipynb):

```
# Reduce cardinality for NEIGHBORHOOD feature

# Get a list of the top 10 neighborhoods
top10 = df['NEIGHBORHOOD'].value_counts()[:10].index

# At locations where the neighborhood is NOT in the top 10, 
# replace the neighborhood with 'OTHER'
df.loc[~df['NEIGHBORHOOD'].isin(top10), 'NEIGHBORHOOD'] = 'OTHER'
```