# How to recategorize values in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with already existing categories instead of raw values, *so I'm wondering what's the best way to recategorize given data*.

Sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(22)
Experience = [
        '2', '6', '0.25', '1',
        '1.5', '5', '0.5', 'more than 10 years',
        '3', '4', 'less than 3 months', '7', '8']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Experience': np.random.choice(Experience, 100),
    'Value': np.random.randint(0, 101, 100)
})

df.groupby('Experience').agg(
    median_value=('Value', 'median'),
    count=('Value', 'count')
)
```

```py
Experience          median_value count
0.25                69.0         7
0.5                 82.0         7
1                   24.0         7
1.5                 36.5         10
2                   50.5         6
3                   74.0         7
4                   40.5         8
5                   51.5         10
6                   70.0         9 
7                   59.0         9
8                   43.0         7
less than 3 months  38.0         5
more than 10 years  59.0         8
```

---

I would like to combine a couple of categories into a single one. For example, `['less than 3 months', '0.25','0.5']` into a `less than a year`.

What I found was that you could use a dictionary (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32263273/10140310) answer):

```py
new_categories = {
    "From 0 to 0.5": ['0.25', '0.5', 'less than 3 months'], 
    "From 1 to 1.5": ['1', '1.5'],
    "2 years": '2'}
categories = {v: k for k,vv in new_categories.items() for v in vv}

df['recategorized'] = df['Experience'].map(categories).astype('category')

df.groupby('recategorized').agg(
    median_value=('Value', 'median'),
    count=('Value', 'count')
)
```

```py
recategorized   median_value    count
2 years         50.5            6
From 0 to 0.5   69.0            19
From 1 to 1.5   33.0            17
```

---

It seems like it works, but is there a better way?

Comment: Don't think there's anything wrong with your current approach. btw: this is a bread and butter example on how to write a good question :)

Comment: @Erfan thanks for the reply. I just thought there would be something built-in similar to `pd.cut` for this case.

Comment: I was thinking about `pd.cut` as well. But the fact you have some values as numbers and some as text like: `less than 3 months` makes this quite an edge case.